# Python http post request format form data

Tags: python, post, request, http-post

**Problem description**
I want to send an http post request to an online [BLAST website](https://www.patricbrc.org/app/BLAST).I inspected the POST requests and saw this:

```
Request URL:https://p3.theseed.org/services/homology_service
Referrer Policy:no-referrer-when-downgrade

Request Headers
Provisional headers are shown
Accept:application/json
Content-Type:application/x-www-form-urlencoded
Origin:https://www.patricbrc.org
Referer:https://www.patricbrc.org/
User-Agent:Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/61.0.3163.100 Safari/537.36
X-Requested-With:XMLHttpRequest

Form Data
{"method":"HomologyService.blast_fasta_to_database","params":[">test
ATAGCTAACAGCATC","blastn","ref.fna","10",50,0],"version":"1.1","id":"27057295081137034"}:
```

Now I want to do this for several sequences (so replacing the `ATAGCTAACAGCATC` ). I'm familiar with sending these type of request, however I don't now how to:

- Format the `form data`, so I can send it using [Requests](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/)
- What I should do with the `id` in the post, because I don't know this because it's unique for every BLAST job.

**Code**

```
 import requests as r

blast_url = 'https://p3.theseed.org/services/homology_service'
data = {"method":"HomologyService.blast_fasta_to_database","params":["%3Etest%0ATAGCTAACAGCATC","blastp","ref.faa","10",'50','0'],"version":"1.1"}
headers = {
            'Host': 'p3.theseed.org',
            'Accept': 'application/json',
            'Accept-Language': 'en-US,en;q=0.5',
            'Referer': 'https://www.patricbrc.org/app/BLAST',
            'Content-Type': 'application/rqlquery+x-www-form-urlencoded',
            'X-Requested-With' : 'XMLHttpRequest'
        }

res = r.post(blast_url, headers = headers, params = data).text
print(res)
```

I didn't fill in the `id`, but that doesn't seem to be a problem because in the error message the id is filled in (so it seems to generated it automatically?)
This is the error I get:

```
{"id":"15004153692662703","error":{"name":"JSONRPCError","code":-32700,"message":"You did not supply any JSON to parse in the POST body."},"version":"1.1"}
```

So obviously the wrong formatting for the form data gives these problems, but I have no idea how I should format this (and if this will fix the problem)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You got malformed json string as error so remote api is expecting data to be of json format. You need to do

```
import json
data = json.dumps(data)
res = r.post(blast_url, headers = headers, data = data).text
```

And make content type of your header as:

```
headers['Content-Type'] = 'application/json'
```

Answer (score 0):

You should change this line `res = r.post(blast_url, headers = headers, params = data).text` to `res = r.post(blast_url, headers = headers, data = data).text`

Also, before using some tools, please read documentation of this tool, for example, dosc for requests you can find [here](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/user/quickstart/)

Comment: I have read that, but the answer isn't working, this will produce an error: {"error":{"name":"JSONRPCError","message":"Error while parsing JSON HTTP request: malformed JSON string, neither tag, array, object, number, string or atom, at character offset 0 (before \"method=HomologyServi...\") at /disks/patric-common/runtime/lib/perl5/site_perl/5.20.2/x86_64-linux/Moose/Meta/Method/Delegation.pm line 110.\n","code":-32700},"version":"1.1","id":"27057295081137034"}

Comment: @CodeNoob, Check my answer, if it does not work then let me know I can post another solution to this